# NSLocalized Strings showing Key in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift4

I’ve been working on an app that I use NSLocalized Strings but when I run the app it’s showing me the key for the localized string and not the string itself. 
Example:
Create a Class initializer.

```
class TestClass {
    let name: String

    init(myName: String) {
        name = myName
    }
}
```

Initialize my Test.

```
class TestString {
    var list = [TestClass]()
    init() {
        list.append(TestClass(myName: NSLocalizedString("Don", comment: "Test 1")))
        list.append(TestClass(myName: NSLocalizedString("Amanda", comment: "Test 2")))
    }
}
```

And my View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var allNames = TestString()
    var count = 0

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = allNames.list[count].name
        count += 1
    }
}
```

The String file is:

```
"Don" = "Donald Belliveau";
"Amanda" = "Amanda Ferguson";
```

When I run the app, I should see my label display Donald Belliveau once I click the button but I'm seeing Don. This was working just last week (Swift 4.0) but now doesn't seem to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure that your Localizable.strings file is actually being included into the project?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka yup. It’s there and selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try & debug the string value by using the following code:

```
NSLocalizedString("Don", tableName: "Localized", bundle: Bundle.main, comment: "")
```

Make sure:

- **tableName** should be exactly the same as the string file name
- **bundle** should the exactly your project bundle name.